# spring boot: "Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction;

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

The full exception is:"

```
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@1847d2b9] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory$EmbeddedDataSourceProxy@2d4.
```

I am new in spring boot, an I use the `@Transactional` in my sercice class,

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class OperationActivitySettingService extends AbstractService {}
```

This is my config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.dp.*")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

but, when i start tomcat and use my service, then will throw exception as above.

Comment: That probably isn't your full configuration, please add the full config. When using Spring Boot you can remove the `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EnableTransactionManagement` as that is already detected by the Spring Boot.

Comment: I ain't sure but, you may try changing the `basePackages` to "com.dp", assuming that that is your project's base package.

Comment: first thanks for your reply, but it does not work anymore@M. Deinum.

Comment: It may help to know what your `AbstractService` looks like. In addition to the removals @M.Deinum recommends, I would also remove the `@Transactional` annotation from your service class and only use that annotation on methods which need it. Finally, with Spring Boot it's probably worth removing `basePackages` from your `@ComponentScan` and putting your application config class in that package directly. That way Spring Boot will auto-configure everything it finds under that package.